# Strange pagination behaviour of /search/excerpts

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2.2, search, paging

In an attempt to (automatically) restore broken images* which have originally been included as HTTP links, I've tried to use [/search/excerpts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) to look for candidate posts; specifically, I'm setting the `url` parameter to `http://*`.

I'm using the maximum page size of 100. This works fine for pages [1](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/excerpts?page=1&pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=creation&url=http%3A%2F%2F*&site=math&filter=!1zT)G6KBq6DLh6wGVEcoH) to [99](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/excerpts?page=99&pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=creation&url=http%3A%2F%2F*&site=math&filter=!1zT)G6KBq6DLh6wGVEcoH), and page 99 says `"has_more": true`, but page [100](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/excerpts?page=100&pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=creation&url=http%3A%2F%2F*&site=math&filter=!1zT)G6KBq6DLh6wGVEcoH) and further pages come up empty. The latest post of page 99 is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53340/228959), dated July 23rd, 2011, and when I use that as the `fromDate` parameter, I'm also getting [newer results](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/excerpts?page=1&pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=creation&url=http%3A%2F%2F*&site=math&filter=!1zT)G6KBq6DLh6wGVEcoH&fromdate=1311379200).

It's not that this particular route has a page maximum of 99; page [100](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/excerpts?page=100&pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=creation&url=http%3A%2F%2F*&site=stackoverflow&filter=!1zT)G6KBq6DLh6wGVEcoH) of the same query on Stack Overflow is populated just fine.

Any idea what's going on here?

*<sub>: I am throttling actual edit attempts to avoid flooding the homepage.</sub>

Comment: I think there might be bugs listed elsewhere [metase], metaSO, etc. that also cover this. (Don't have time to search ATM.)

Comment: Also, appears to still be a problem in API version 2.3

Comment: Ah, well, at least I've found a useful workaround :)